# How do I change the permalinks to #1, #2, #3?

Tags: 7, theming, comments, nodes

I would like to change the comment/forum links to something like:

TOPIC:

```
#1

#2

#3
```

Do you have any idea on how should I do this?

Comment: Could you give an example on what you'd like it to look like?

Comment: Sure - http://eu.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/2151761416 - at the right side the is #1,#2,#3 etc.

Comment: It's the same permalink of course but named properly (# + count).

Comment: Ah, I think I get it now. You're talking about *displaying* these links, not altering the actual links.

Answer (score 4):

[Advanced forum](http://drupal.org/project/advanced_forum) provides what you are looking for out of the box (a #number permalink in the upper left corner of the post) among tons of other useful features for a forum.

You could either simply use that module, or you could look at it's template files to see how it's done. The relevant code seems to be in [includes/advanced_forum_preprocess_comment.inc](http://drupalcode.org/project/advanced_forum.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-2.x:/includes/advanced_forum_preprocess_comment.inc) and looks like this.

```
  /* Linked post number */
  if (!isset($post_number)) {
    static $post_number = 1;
  }

  $posts_per_page = variable_get('comment_default_per_page_' . $node->type, 50);

  $page_number = !empty($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 0;
  if (!$page_number) {
    $page_number = 0;
  }

  $post_number++;

  $linktext = '#' . (($page_number * $posts_per_page) + $post_number);

  // Permalink
  //  You can erase next 3 lines if you wish to use built-in Permalink.
  //  Template adjusted: $post_link -> $permalink
      $uri = entity_uri('comment', $comment);
  $uri['options'] += array('attributes' => array('class' => 'permalink', 'rel' => 'bookmark'));
  $variables['permalink'] = l($linktext, $uri['path'], $uri['options']);
```

Comment: Does it work for an article comment as well ?

Comment: Advanced forum does it only for forum comments, but you can addapt it for all comments. You need to place that code in a comment preprocess function like adv_forum does and then use the $permalink variable in your template.

Comment: Is the `if (!$page_number) { $page_number = 0; }` part necessary? It would  just set `$page_number` to 0, which is already done from the previous line.

Answer (score 3):

First, if the code is in `template_preprocess_comment(&$vars)`, `$node->type` needs to be `$vars['node']->type`. Also, there isn't the need of a comment counter per each page because the Comment module adds an ID starting with 1 for the top comment. Currently this code works correctly for me with comments on several pages.

```
function template_preprocess_comment(&$vars) {
  $posts_per_page = variable_get('comment_default_per_page_' . $vars['node']->type, 50);

  $page_number = !empty($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 0;
  if (!$page_number) {
    $page_number = 0;
  }

  $linktext = '#' . (($page_number * $posts_per_page) + $vars['id']);

  $vars['comment']->uri['options'] += array('attributes' => array('class' => 'permalink', 'rel' => 'bookmark'));
  $vars['permalink'] = l($linktext, $vars['comment']->uri['path'], $vars['comment']->uri['options']);
}
```

Comment: If that works, then all the better, I know that there have been quite some improvements for comment permalinks in D7. Have you tested this with multiple pages of comments? Is the id always correct?

Comment: That's a good question. The problem is the ID# starts at one for each page which means page_1 which starts with the 11th comment will start numbering comments from #1. The top answer then is the correct answer to this problem.

Comment: this should be marked as answer

Answer (score 2):

OK got it to work properly ! In you template.php file (drupal/sites/adress/themes/YOURTHEME/template.php) add:

```
<?php 

function YOURTHEME!_preprocess_comment(&$variables){

  /* Easy links to the comment and parent node */
  $comment = $variables['comment'];
  $node = node_load($comment->nid);
  $variables['first_post'] = $node; 

  // Set the post ID for theming / targetting
  $variables['post_id'] = "post-$comment->cid";

  /* Linked post number */
  if (!isset($post_number)) {
    static $post_number = 1;
  }

  $posts_per_page = variable_get('comment_default_per_page_' . $node->type, 50);

  $page_number = !empty($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 0;
  if (!$page_number) {
    $page_number = 0;
  }

  $post_number++;

  $linktext = '#' . (($page_number * $posts_per_page) + $post_number);

  // Permalink
  //  You can erase next 3 lines if you wish to use built-in Permalink.
  //  Template adjusted: $post_link -> $permalink
  $uri = entity_uri('comment', $comment);
  $uri['options'] += array('attributes' => array('class' => 'permalink', 'rel' => 'bookmark'));
  $variables['permalink'] = l($linktext, $uri['path'], $uri['options']);

}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can type in your css file something like this:

.comment .submitted .permalink{
    display: none;
}

and no more permalink ;)